# Updated images for Styled Media Receiver aren't showing up

Tags: chromecast

I created a Styled Media Receiver. Hosted the css and images on AWS S3. I started showing up after few hours. Then I changed the images for logo and splash, but, still old images are showing up. I even factory reset the chromecast and connected again, but no respite.

Does anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same name for the updated images, maybe S3 is caching the images or css? Try renaming them and update your styled application settings and see if that does any good. You can also start a chrome debug session and see what images are pointing at to catch any possible issues that way as well.